# How to check two string inside if condition

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements, nested-if

I know this is a bit of a silly question and sorry for that. But I bit confused about this.

I need to check when `backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage` not equal `Success` or `Success2` need to set `validationResult = backToLobbyStatus;` So I wrote code as,

```
if (  (assistCustomer != null && backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage != "Success") 
   || (assistCustomer != null && backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage != "Success2")) {
 validationResult = backToLobbyStatus;
}
```

but when `backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage == "Success"`, this conditon `assistCustomer != null && backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage != "Success2"` getting true, What did I do wrong here. How to handle this properly without nested if condtion. or is nested if is the most proper way to handle this error?

Comment: you could do `assistCustomer != null && !(new string[] { "Success", "Success2" }.Contains(backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage))`

Comment: Believe what you need is `if((assistCustomer != null) && (backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage != "Success" && backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage != "Success2"))`

Comment: You need to early return if `assistCustomer == null`

Answer (score 1):

Don't do the same comparison `(assistCustomer!=null)` twice:

```
if (assistCustomer != null)
{
   if(backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage != "Success") 
   || backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage != "Success2")
   {
     validationResult = backToLobbyStatus;
   }
}
```

It makes it easier to see that the comparison is "is error message not Success OR not Success2.

If error message is "Success" then it can't be "Success2", so the second comparison will trigger.
I suspect you actually want `&&` instead of `||`

```
   if(backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage != "Success") 
   && backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage != "Success2")
   {
     validationResult = backToLobbyStatus;
   }
```

Comment: As u mentioned if I use `&&` , I think to execute `validationResult = backToLobbyStatus;` `ErrorMessage ` both condtion should be true

Comment: @Adam, do you want to achieve "do nothing if `Success1` or `Success2`"? If yes, you may check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using early return, which will reduce nested statements.

```
if(assistCustomer == null){
    return;
}
if ( backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage == "Success") || ( backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage == "Success2") { 
    return;
}
validationResult = backToLobbyStatus;
```

Early return rules out any "easy to judge" cases earlier and deal with complex cases.

In general, early return any invalid cases, so you could handle the normal case in he end.

However your "normal" case is handling invalid cases, which might happen sometimes.

This practice is useful and easy to achieve.
I will suggest to use it as much as possible, unless there is only one statement and you're confident of it never growing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enumerable.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.8) with an array, eg :

```
var successMessages=new[]{"Success","Success2"};

...
if (assistCustomer != null  && !successMessages.Contains(backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage))
{
    ...
}
```

You could use a different collection like `HashSet<T>` to speed up lookups but with just 2 elements, it's not really worth it.

Answer (score -1):

Use the method String.IsNullOrEmpty() to check for null and use String.Equals() for comparison. 
Here's a better solution

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage)
{
 validationResult = ((backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage.Equals("Success") ||
                   backToLobbyStatus.ErrorMessage.Equals("Success2"))?
                   backToLobbyStatus: string.empty; 
}
```

Comment: Don't use `.Equals` unless you need to override the comparison (say to ignore case or use a different CultureInfo). Idiomatic C# uses `==`.  My guess would be you learnt Java before C# :-)

Comment: @Neil there is nothing bad about using `.Equals`. When you use `==` compiler still going to call `.Equals`so it is identical and it's your personal preference what to use

Comment: @OlegI There's nothing wrong with using `.Equals` if you *need to*, but in this case, you don't, and it's more idiomatic of C# to use `==`.

Comment: I've updated the code, it just occurred to me that we can achieve the same result with a conditional statement too so why not!